# Baking at a lower temperature than the recipe calls for

Tags: baking

The recipe calls for 350 degrees for 10 minutes, yet my oven only goes up to 260 degrees. How long should the cake stay in the oven?

Comment: What are you trying to bake, and are you sure it's not calling for fahrenheit temperatures rather then centigrade?

Comment: I'm assuming you're mixing temperature scales. No household oven would go anywhere near 350C - certainly no cake I've ever baked has needed to be baked that high.

Comment: If your oven really could do 350C, you would probably get an almost catastrophic result as mixing psi and bar for inflating tires, or using pounds instead of litres when fueling your aircraft

Comment: @VirtualAnomaly The self cleaning cycle is significantly hotter on many ovens, so it's not a matter of capability.

Comment: Reminds me of a joke shared with a [potter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiln): “fire on cone nine”.

Comment: @Random832 Maybe, but you shouldn't use the cleaning cycle for cooking...

Answer (score 46):

Convert 350°F to 175°C - I don't think there's any lower temperature issue here.

If your oven goes up to 260 degrees, I'm guessing that's 260°C, not 260°F. (260°C is 500°F, so that's not a surprising maximum temperature to see, whereas a max of 260°F would be a pretty useless oven.)

A cake recipe that calls for 350 degrees is most likely 350°F, especially if you happen to know it's an American recipe. 350°F is an extremely common temperature in American recipes, possibly the most common. (A baking temperature of 350°C is really high and pretty unlikely - pretty much just for things like pizza, and certainly not cake.)

Comment: It may be helpful to note that 350F is an extremely common temperature for baking cakes if you are using an American (et.al) recipe.

Comment: @Keeta There isn't really any "et al." to the use of Fahrenheit. It's hard to imagine a British book giving Fahrenheit without also giving a [gas mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_Mark) (if it was rather old), Celsius if more modern) or both.

Comment: And of course, 175 - 225 C is a very common temperature range for almost anything oven-related...

Comment: A (nice) reason to also note the [gas mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_Mark) in recipes, especially if you publish them online. Browser translation has gotten .. not quite _good_, but good enough that those with less experience might not realize a different temperature scale is at play :)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Although a stretch, I felt if I didn't include "et al", some SE user in Belize, Bahamas or Cayman Islands would be saying "what about my country?"